# How do I dynamically route through a list of objects in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, routes, angularjs-routing

How can I make this `<a>` tag link to a template that then dynamically populates data based on what project it is linked to?

I *am* able to link to any URL like `'/skreens'`, `'/viewpoint'`, or `'/dogedots'` through the `'project.html'` view,
 but **the template will not dynamically populate the expressions within that template.**

This is my list of projects.

```
<li ng-repeat="project in projects">          
  <a href="#linkUrl">{{project.title}}</a>
</li>
```

And this is the view they link to (project.html)

```
<h1>{{project.title}}</h1> //right now nothing appears here :(
```

The `<a>` link populates its href with static data loaded from

```
angular.module('MyWeb', ['ngRoute'])
  .config( ['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/viewpoint', {
            templateUrl: '/myWebpage/app/templates/project.html'
            controller:'MainControl'
        })
        .when('/dogedots', {
            templateUrl: '/myWebpage/app/templates/project.html',
            controller:'MainControl'
        })
        .when('/skreens', {
            templateUrl: '/myWebpage/app/templates/project.html'
            controller:'MainControl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/',
            templateUrl: '/myWebpage/app/templates/portfolio.html'
        })
  }])
  .controller('MainControl', function($scope){
      $scope.projects = [
         { "id": 0, "linkUrl": "skreens", "title": "Skreens"},
         { "id": 2, "linkUrl": "viewpoint", "title": "ViewPoint Cloud"},
         { "id": 1, "linkUrl": "dogedots", "title": "Doge Dots"}
      ]
  })
```

controller:'MainControl'
but the projects data will not populate the template t

Answer (score 1):

First, to link using ng-router, you should use `ng-href="{{project.linkUrl}}"`. The way you have it defined right now will not work.

As far as the value not showing properly, from what you've posted it doesn't show that you are binding your controller to a view anywhere. This should happen in the .when object. Ex. `.when('/portfolio', { 
  controller:'MainControl',
  templateUrl:'/myWebpage/app/templates/portfolio.html'
})`

Comment: This fix does help progress my code, but I am still unable to populate the `project.html` page with the data from each `project in projects`. Why did you remove the `#` from `ng-href`?

Comment: I think it will depend how you have your project set up. I also think I am mixing up ui-router with ng-router, I typically prefer the former and forget some of the specifics of ng-router. Does the routing work properly? Otherwise you can try it with `ng-href="#/{{project.linkUrl}}"` . I think I am understanding the problem you are having with the next page. is your link in portfolio.html and linking to project.html where you want to display the title?

Comment: If so, its because the scope from portfolio has been destroyed and a new one created for the next page - it does not know which 'project' is specified, should be undefined. You need to either pass that project name as a route parameter, and then access it from there, or store it in a service. Since a service is a singleton, it should preserve the value of selected project until it is changed.

Comment: You are correct about `portfolio.html` linking to `project.html`.  Using `ng-href="#/{{project.linkUrl}}"` is a success and does link me to `project.html`, however `project.html` does not show data.

Comment: I've updated the question but the `MainControl` is being specified in each route ex. `'/skreens'`, `'/viewpoint'`. Shouldn't the `MainControl`be refreshed once i reroute?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. MainControl will be refreshed, thus the reference to 'project' a specific item in 'projects' will be lost. You need to find a way to preserve that. So like I mentioned, you can do route parameter where it looks something like `ng-href="#/{{project.linkUrl}}/project1"` and then you can use the controller to set `$scope.currentProject = $routeParams.project`, or use a service to store that. then you can call `{{currentProject.title}}` and it should work. Please look into route param docs or services if you need some help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77138/discussion-between-jadams-and-ian-steffy).